# Color RGB in BackColor's Form

Tags: c#, .net, rgb

I'd like to put the RBG color In the property of the form, not like code, but when I try I got this error.

"0, 161, 230 no es un valor válido para Int32."

(not a valid value)

I know I could do something like this:

```
this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 161, 230);
```

But it doesn't give me a preview about the color.

What's wrong?

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: If you mean that you would like to change the backcolor directly in the designer try this:   0;161;230

Comment: I can type `0, 161, 230` in to the property for BackColor and it works with no problems.  But I cannot enter `0; 161; 230` because then I get "0; 161; 230 is not a valid value for Int32."  So is this perhaps a locale thing specific to Spanish?  I'm aware that comma is used like a decimal place in some locales.  To determine the syntax I pulled down the arrow, and selected the _custom_ tab, and entered some random color.  Then it showed me the color in discrete RGB using the right syntax.  Perhaps you could try the same?

Comment: @Suppe Solved! Thanks!! :)

Comment: @Wyck Yep, it seems in spanish is kind of different, I was watching videos in English, that's why I tried with "R, G, B" instead of "R;G;B"... Seems we're such a weirdos... Thanks :)

Comment: Im from sweden and using the english version of visual studio, not possible for me to use the comma...